# How to add button to FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I need to add a button to `FragmentTabHost`. How to build something like this?

[image: FragmentTabHost]

```
FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_host);

tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
        R.id.tab_content);

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("TAB 1"),
        MatchStatisticsFragment.class, null);

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("TAB 2"),
        EventsListFragment.class, null); 
// can I add right-align button there?
```

Answer (score 2):

Its the menu button, shown icon only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon"
          android:title="@string/title"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```